# $X \models S_f(\mathcal O,\mathcal O)$ implies $X \models S_1(\mathcal O,\mathcal O)$

Tags: general-topology

I have a problem with a begining of a proof in a course that I am reading. I bring here the definitions and statement:

**Definition (Rothberger):** For $k \in \mathbb N$, a space $\langle X,O \rangle$ satisfies Rothberger ptoperty or $S_k(\mathcal O,\mathcal O)$, iff for any family of open covers of $X$, $\langle \mathcal U_n | n \in \mathbb N \rangle$ there exists some
$\langle \mathcal F_n \in [\mathcal U_n]^k | n \in \mathbb N \rangle$ such that $\bigcup _{n \in \mathbb N} \mathcal F_n$ covers $X$.

**Observation:** For a topological space $\langle X,O \rangle$, TFAE:

1.$X \models S_1(\mathcal O,\mathcal O)$

2.$X \models S_k(\mathcal O,\mathcal O)$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$

3.$X \models S_f(\mathcal O,\mathcal O)$ for some $f \in \mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$. i.e. for any family of open covers of $X$, $\langle \mathcal U_n | n \in \mathbb N \rangle$, 
There exists a family $\langle \mathcal F_n \in [\mathcal U_n]^{f(n)} | n \in \mathbb N \rangle$ such that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}  \mathcal F_n $ is an open cover of $X$.

**Proof:** To see $(c) \Rightarrow (a)$, fix $f \in \mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$, such that $X \models S_f(\mathcal O,\mathcal O)$. Pick an arbitrary partition $\langle A_n \in [\mathbb N]^{f(n)} \rangle$ with $\uplus_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n = \mathbb N$.
For all $n \in \mathbb N$, Let $\mathcal V_n := \{ \bigcap Im(g) | g \in \Pi_{m \in A_n} \mathcal U_m \}$. **Evidently, each $\mathcal V_n$ covers $X$**...

My question is: How can we conclude that each $\mathcal V_n$ covers $X$?
To me, it seems like, for each $n \in \mathbb N$, $\mathcal V_n$ is an open subset of $X$. What am I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $\mathcal{V}_n$ consists of finite intersections of open subsets of $X$ (since $\mathrm{Im}(g)$ is a finite set of open subsets of $X$), so it is a collection of open sets (and not an open subset of $X$).

Second, note that the particular $A_n$ and $\langle \mathcal{U}_m \mid m\in A_n \rangle$ are not important, so let's reduce the number of symbols we are dealing with.

Fix a natural number $k$. For $1 \leq i \leq k$, let $\mathcal{U}_i$ be an open cover. We want to prove that $\{\bigcap \mathrm{Im}(g) \mid g \in \Pi_{1 \leq i \leq k} \mathcal{U}_i\}$ is an open cover of $X$. We do this by induction on $k$. The base case $k =1$ is clear.

For $1 \leq i < k$, fix $h \in \Pi_{1 \leq i < k} \mathcal{U}_i$ and let $V_h = \bigcap_{1 \leq i <k}h(i)$. Let $G_h = \{g \in \Pi_{1 \leq i \leq k}\mathcal{U}_i \mid 1 \leq i <k \implies g(i) = h(i)\}$.

Then for $g \in G_h$, $\bigcap \mathrm{Im}(g) = V_h \cap g(k)$. So $\bigcup\{\bigcap \mathrm{Im}(g) \mid g \in G_h\} = \bigcup \{V \cap U\mid U \in \mathcal{U}_k\} = V_h $.

So, $\bigcup \{\bigcap \mathrm{Im}(g) \mid g \in \Pi_{1 \leq i \leq k} \mathcal{U}_i\} = \bigcup\{\bigcup\{\bigcap \mathrm{Im}(g) \mid g \in G_h\} \mid {h \in \Pi_{1 \leq i < k}}\mathcal{U}_i\} = \bigcup \{V_h \mid {h \in \Pi_{1 \leq i < k}} \mathcal{U}_i\}$.

And this is equal to $X$ by the inductive hypothesis.

So each of the $\mathcal{V}_n$ in the question are open covers of $X$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I am trying to go over it but I think I am missing something basic. For example. If $k=1$, we get $g \in \mathcal U_1$. Doesn't that mean that $g$ is an open set from the cover $\mathcal U_1$? If yes, then how can a singel open set cover all of $X$. If not, then, what is $g$ in the case $k=1$?

Comment: @ShirSivroni If $k=1$, then $g$ is a function with domain $\{1\}$ and range $\mathcal{U}_1$. I agree that the notation is a bit problematic, but from what I understand of the question, $g$ is always a function with a finite domain, and for each $i$ in its domain, $g(i)$ is an element of the cover $\mathcal{U}_i$.

Comment: So, in the case $k=1$, what is Im(g)? isn't it a single open set from $\mathcal U_1$? so, why can we say that $\bigcap Im(g)$ is a cover of $X$. One open set will usually not be a cover of the whole space.. I still don't get it :(

Comment: In this case, $\mathrm{Im}(g) = \{g(1)\}$, which is a singleton set, which contains an open set (it is not a single open set, it is the set whose only contents are this set). And $\bigcap \mathrm{Im}(g) = g(1)$, which is a single open set. So, taking the collection of $\bigcap \mathrm{Im}(g)$ over all such $g$, we get the set $\mathcal{U}_1$, which by assumption is an open cover.

Comment: I get it now.  this was driving me creazy.... Thank you!!!